# Is there a way to remove all mutationObservers from the item without reference to it?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, browser, mutation-observers

Specifically one of my chrome extensions adds MutationsObserver on whole body. Is there any way to prevent this or remove all observers from body in runtime?

Comment: No, there's no way to remove it but you can remove the entire document.body element and add it back (in case the extension doesn't re-attach the observer dynamically).

Comment: Could also patch `MutationObserver.prototype.observe` and have it not do anything if called from the extension

Comment: Patching prototypes won't help because extensions run content scripts in isolated world.

Answer (score 2):

MutationObservers are not attached to the DOM, so if you replace the body with a copy of itself, the observers will be disconnected (and garbage collected). Try this:

```
document.body = document.body.cloneNode(true);
```

Comment: wow, that's amazing!

Comment: Beware that quite sure all event listeners added by code will be lost also

Comment: Yes, I found that issue, but I think it is acceptable, thanks :) To minimalize the effect, we can use `replaceChild(new_elm, old_elm)` to replace the parent node

Answer (score 1):

A way to keep childnodes events:

```js
var body = document.createElement('body');
for(var node of document.body.childNodes)
  body.appendChild(node);
document.body.replaceWith(body);
```