# How to append HTML elment to telegra.ph P element?

Tags: javascript, html, element

I'm building a chrome extension, and I want to append some element to [this telegraph page](https://telegra.ph/Test-01-16-201), it seems only text is appended successfully, but not the entire HTML.

```js
const span = document.createElement("span");
span.innerHTML = '<span class="xxx">Foo,bar</span>';
const p = document.querySelector("p");
p.appendChild(span);
```

Comment: I [can't reproduce the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/sLg7z32u/). Please create a [mre].

Comment: @Teemu, Thanks, so maybe it's not because of `contenteditable` attribute? you can open [the page](https://telegra.ph/Test-01-16-201) , and open the devtools to run the code,  you'll see only the `text` `Foo,bar` is appended, but not the HTML.

Comment: @OwenYoung - What result do you want? A span containing `Foo,bar` or the **text** `<span>Foo,bar</span>`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder a span containing Foo, bar .

Comment: Some code on the page is being triggered (perhaps by a `MutationObserver`, perhaps by monkey-patching), and interfering with/adjusting what you append. If you take that exact HTML structure and use it in isolation, your code actually appends a `span`. Unless you can find out what library is being used to do that and see if it offers a way to do this, you're probably stuck.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder , thanks, I'll figure out if there is another way to handle my job.

Comment: Thanks, I have removed the `contenteditable` from the description.

Comment: As suggested I verified there's actually a MutationObserver that just changes the dom in real time when some code attempted to change something. Since there's no way to find the instances of live MutationObserver unless you can clearly find the variable in some obscure scope, the quickest way is to just replace the body element with its clone and all MutationObservers will be gone. `document.body = document.body.cloneNode(true);` after that if you append elements to the dom it will change as intended.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61572748/is-there-a-way-to-remove-all-mutationobservers-from-the-item-without-reference-t I found the solution here because I had no idea it was going to work as that. I was stuck still trying to find the variable that is somewhere in quill.min.js I think

Comment: @DiegoD, Thanks very much! it works, and it perfectly solved my use case. maybe you should answer it as an answer.

Comment: So I did @OwenYoung I also asked myself why I didn't since the beginning but probably because I felt it was very very very close to the original one. Anyway actually it's addressing your specific problem and that one happens to be the reason behind. So.. glad it worked.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in comments I verified myself there's actually a `MutationObserver` that just changes the dom in real time when some code attempted to mutate something at some point in the document tree.

Since there's no standard way to find the instances, if any, of live MutationObservers listening on the dom, unless you can put efforts finding in which scope is the variable holding that object; the quickest way is to just replace the body element with its clone, and all MutationObservers will be gone.

```
 document.body = document.body.cloneNode(true);
```

after doing that, when you'll try to append elements to the dom, it will change accordingly as intended with no interference.

### In all fairness...

The final clue was found in a Stack Overflow answer when looking for how to fetch for live MutationObserver instances or what's the working approach to solve that need?

[Is there a way to remove all mutationObservers from the item without reference to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61572748/is-there-a-way-to-remove-all-mutationobservers-from-the-item-without-reference-t)